# How to read image files/Machine Learning Image Recognition?

Tags: python, machine-learning, image-processing, artificial-intelligence

I was thinking about creating an image recognition model using python and some machine-learning libraries, (ie. keras, tensorflow...) I was wondering if anybody could enlighten me as to which libraries are recommended for such things. (I have done image recognition projects before, but never at the scale that I am planning now). My plan is to be able to detect ASL letters and numbers, and eventually words and such. My first roadblock about how should I transform example pictures into readable files (ie. arrays with ones and zeros for black and white, or if I should even do this). Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yeah, better to follow an online tutorial first and get some idea some the domain and start hands-on sessions on python. down the line, you need python a lot. try to polish your skills first. and then start some online tutorials

Comment: Please **re-read** [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), as it would seem that you missed some crucial points the first time you read it, namely that questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most computer vision applications I know in Python typically use one of these three options to load into numpy arrays:

- [Scikit-Image](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.html)
- [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/) (NOTE: reads BGR instead of RGB)
- [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

PyTorch has [some tutorials](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/pytorch-pil-to-tensor-and-vice-versa/6312) demonstrating support for Pillow (PIL) if deep learning is your goal, although once you have the numpy array it's fairly easy to use any Python image processing/computer vision library and transfer to the desired format. Any of these are viable options for most large scale image processing applications.

Comment: Kindly refrain from answering off-topic questions, as advised in the community guidelines - please see [Should one advise on off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions), [“Why shouldn't I answer off-topic questions?” FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262573/why-shouldnt-i-answer-off-topic-questions-faq), and [Should I answer off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133552/should-i-answer-off-topic-questions)